# images are not displaying in executable jar

Tags: java, image, swing, resources, system-tray

i have created executable jar file of my project built in eclipse. but when i execute that file then it does not display icon on system tray that i have added in project. i am using following simple code.

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/ChatIcon1.jpeg");
PopupMenu Popup = new PopupMenu();
MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
Popup.add(exit);

final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image,"OfficeCommunicator",Popup);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
```

Comment: Remove `src/resources/` from the URL and put `ChatIcon1.jpeg` at the root folder of your project if you want to access the file outside an executable jar. But, if you want it as part of the executable jar's resources, then use `getClass.getResource()` method to retrieve it.

Comment: @Vinay : Are you packaging your `Source Code` with your `.jar` file ?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load resources from within .jar files please use getClass().getResource(). That will return a URL with correct path.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("path to image"));
```

Comment: thanks. but can can you give full line of code because i dont know how to try it on Image.